# register concrete type with ctor parameter using structuremap

Tags: c#-4.0, structuremap

I need  to register all concrete type of a specific interface with structuremap

the problem I have is that these concrete types just have a ctor with primitive parameters, and these parameters would be dynamiclly differen

```
public interface IPropertyType 
{
    string PropertyName { get; set; }

    string DisplayName { get; set; }

}

 public abstract class PropertyTypeBase :  IPropertyType
{

    public PropertyTypeBase(string propertyName, string displayName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
}


 public class StringType : PropertyTypeBase
{

    public StringType(string propertyName, string displayName)
        : base(propertyName,displayName)
    {
       //do sth
    }

}
```

all concrete types like **StringType** have these 2 parameter that are different from each other and they would declare during run time, how can I register all of these types

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that both properties are public get and set I would remove them from your constructor. I see no reason at all why you would want to have these injected as they're not dependencies and can be reset afterwards anyway.

Comment: the reason is clear, i dont want to be able to create instance without having those properties, although I can change them later!!

Comment: You could use `ObjectFactory.With(string)` or make a class containing these 2 strings so you can inject this class as well? I don't really see how 2 strings are a dependency you wish to inject.